# PHPexcel get highest sheet index range

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, phpexcel, phpexcelreader

I am using PHPExcel for import data from excel file.
but I find some problems where the data was dynamically repeated per sheets and I wanted to take the last sheet to process.
Is there any idea or method to get the highest sheet index ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Get the total number of sheets:

```
$sheetCount = $excelObj->getSheetCount();
```

The last sheet index will be:

```
$lastSheet = $sheetCount - 1;
```

Comment: Thanks ! It Works Ben :D

Comment: @MochamadZaula Glad I could help! If it solved your problem don't forget to accept it as the answer, thank you :)